# Audio visualization android code with the moving line

Tags: android

I need to write Audio Visualisation code which shows the graph and the moving line indicating the current position. I have written the code to get the graph in my View. I get the amplitudes from MediaRecorder and use Canvas.drawline to get the graph. In order to get the moving line indicating the current position, that keeps constantly changing - what do I do? The shape that I draw either a rectangle or line keeps continuously getting drawn. How do I make the previous one (line or rectangle) disappear? Or just have the shape move to new coordinates

I am just posting the VisualizerView Code

```
public class VisualizerView extends View {

private static final int LINE_WIDTH = 5; //width of visualier lines
private static final int LINE_SCALE = 150; //scales visualiEr lines
private List<Float> amplitudes;
private int viewWidth;
private int viewHeight;
private Paint linePaint; //line drawing characteristics
private Paint currentLinePointer;
ShapeDrawable mRect;

public VisualizerView (Context ctx, AttributeSet attrs){
    super (ctx, attrs);
    linePaint = new Paint ();
    linePaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    linePaint.setStrokeWidth(LINE_WIDTH);

    currentLinePointer = new Paint();
    currentLinePointer.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    currentLinePointer.setStrokeWidth(LINE_WIDTH);

    mRect = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());
    mRect.getPaint().setColor(Color.RED);

}

//when dimensions of view changes
@Override
public void onSizeChanged (int w, int h, int oldW, int newH){
    viewWidth = w;
    viewHeight = h;
    amplitudes = new ArrayList<Float>(viewWidth/LINE_WIDTH);

}

@Override
public void onDraw (Canvas canvas){
    int middle = viewHeight/2; 
    int curX = 0;

    //for each item in amplitudes Arraylist
    for (float power: amplitudes){
        float scaledHeight = power/LINE_SCALE; //scale the power
        curX += LINE_WIDTH ; //imcrease by line widht

       // currentLinePointer.setColor(Color.RED);
       // canvas.drawLine(curX, middle + viewHeight/2,  curX, middle -viewHeight/2, currentLinePointer);

        mRect.setVisible(true, true);
        mRect.setBounds ((int)curX , middle - viewHeight/2, (int) curX+ LINE_WIDTH, middle + viewHeight/2);
        mRect.draw(canvas);
        canvas.drawLine(curX, middle + scaledHeight/2, curX, middle - scaledHeight/2, linePaint);

      //THIS RECTANGLE NEEDS TO KEEP MOVING .... CANNOT FIGURE HOW TO MOVE IT.
        mRect.setVisible(false, false);
        mRect.invalidateSelf();

    }

}

public void clear (){
    amplitudes.clear();
}

public void addAmplitude (float amplitude){
    amplitudes.add(amplitude);

    if (amplitudes.size() * LINE_WIDTH >= viewWidth){
        amplitudes.remove(0); //remove the oldest width
    }
}

}
```

Comment: please post your code

Comment: Thanks. Just posted

Answer (score 0):

A pretty silly mistake. I need to have the line or rectangle code outside the current position line outside the loop where the amplitude gets drawn in onDraw. Solved it.

```
    @Override
    public void onDraw (Canvas canvas){
    int middle = viewHeight/2; //middle of view
    int curX = 0;

    //for each item in amplitudes Arraylist
    for (float power: amplitudes){
        float scaledHeight = power/LINE_SCALE; //scale the power
        curX += LINE_WIDTH ; //imcrease by line widht

        // draw a line representing this item in the amplitudes ArrayList

        canvas.drawLine(curX, middle + scaledHeight/2, curX, middle - scaledHeight/2, linePaint);


    }
    canvas.drawLine(curX, middle + viewHeight/2,  curX, middle -viewHeight/2, currentLinePointer);

}
```